# Allow anonymous users to send email to a certain user in MediaWiki

Tags: php, email, permissions, user-controls, mediawiki

I have an all-core MediaWiki 1.33.0 website (no added extensions or skins).

Normally in MediaWiki, a registered user can send email to another registered user through the latter's user profile (and if the latter permitted getting emails from other registered users).

My problem is that anonymous users cannot send emails to a registered users as described.

I desire to allow anonymous users to send emails to registered users through their profile just a registered user would, so that the option *"Send an email to that user"* in sidebar, will appear for an anonymous user visiting a relevant user's profile.

### Potential solution

There are PHP extensions for MediaWiki that allow a contact form available for all users, like [ContactPage](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ContactPage) but I desire an extensionless solution if there is one (I prefer this to reduce complexity).

### My question

As a non PHP developer I ask; is there a PHP hook (or tweak?) usable in `LocalSettings.php` to allow anonymous users to send me email through that profile?
If not, is there a Wiki syntax API call or an [AJAJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#AJAJ) call to bypass the PHP restriction?

<sub>[Original discussion in MediaWiki community](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:V5ynrqu3t1guz1rj)</sub>

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to reimplement ContactPage inside LocalSettings.php? Probably, but it seems like a pretty bad idea.

Comment: Hello dear Tgr. I ask how to remove the restriction on anonymous users to send email to a registered user. Thanks,

Comment: To clarify @Tgr I seek a solution that does not require installing any extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as it is only you, it might be possible to allow anonymous users to send emails to any user by granting them the `sendemail` user right via *LocalSettings.php*

I don't know if that's a great idea though, and mind I have not tested it.

Comment: Thank you, up voted for you being the first one to come with a non extension related idea. Please consider to share some code example or code hint explaining if you would change or add anything to `LocalSettings.php`.

Comment: In the end I used Contact Page extension, thank you.